# maxage option in logrotate not working as expected

Tags: logs, logrotate

I am rotating my logs using **logrotate** in linux. I want to remove my logs older than **7** days. So I tried **maxage** option in **logrotate** but it is not working as expected.

Let say I have 6 logs which is created in the order shown below

```
Date            filename

18th oct    sample.log.2017-10-18
17th oct    sample.log.2017-10-17
16th oct    sample.log.2017-10-16
15th oct    sample.log.2017-10-15
14th oct    sample.log.2017-10-14
13th oct    sample.log.2017-10-13
12th oct    sample.log.2017-10-12
```

Today(**19th oct**) no sample log is created so no log is rotated and also **sample.log.2017-10-12** needs to be deleted but it is not deleted why?

find logrotate property file below

```
/var/log/test/*.log {

    missingok
    notifempty
    nocompress
    daily
    dateext
    dateformat .%Y-%m-%d
    maxage 7

}
```

Comment: According to the man pages for log rotate, "maxage count - Remove rotated logs older than <count> days.  The  age  is  only checked if the logfile is to be rotated." Since there was no rotation, there no check

Comment: @RamanSailopal. okay. so is there any way we can achieve this without rotation

Comment: Use the find command with -ctime/mtime and -delete

Comment: @RamanSailopal if i include that in post rotate same will happen right if there is  no rotation

Comment: You will need to run the find and delete of another process, maybe off a daily cron job.

Answer (score -2):

Your glob pattern is incomplete - it only matches logs that end with `.log`. The logs you want to delete after 7 days all end `.log.[0-9-]*`.

Comment: The logs are rotated with a date extension rather than with a sequential numerical `.1`, `.2` (etc.) suffix. This is achieved with the `dateext` option in the shown configuration (together with `dateformat` which sets the format of the extension). The actual logfile is called `sample.log` and the list of names that they show are the already rotated logs.

Comment: Yes @Kusalananda I see that. The glob pattern I provided is not invalid, I included a wild card which would result in matching all the rotated logs.